# Doctrine delete items from collection - different column name

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have problem with Doctrine collection. In *PromoCodeTerm* entity I have `@OneToMany $days` collection, but when doctrine delete items from this collection, generates SQL query with different column name, like a **promoCodeTerm** instead of **promo_code_term_id**.

```
class PromoCodeTerm {

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var PromoCodeTermDay[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\PromoCode\PromoCodeTermDay", mappedBy="promoCodeTerm", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $days;
}

class PromoCodeTermDay {

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="day_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     */
    private $day;

    /**
     * @var PromoCodeTerm
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\PromoCode\PromoCodeTerm", inversedBy="days")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="promo_code_term_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ORM\Id()
     */
    private $promoCodeTerm;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM `promo_code__promo_code_term_day` WHERE `day` = ? AND `promoCodeTerm` = ?' with params [1, \"c2fce03a-0507-47ca-a060-362cce683b06\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'promoCodeTerm' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Which doctrine version are u using?

Comment: Can you post your delete query using entity manager, not just plain SQL. Seems like you should join PromoCodeTermDay with PromoCodeTerm and use it's id in where clause.

Comment: Doctrine2, doctrine/orm 2.5.13

Comment: Can you also add the code where you delete the entity?

Comment: Maybe you have a many-to-many relation with PromoCodeTermDay from another entity that causes your issue. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929620/wrong-fieldname-in-query-with-criteria-and-many-to-many-relation/47231219#47231219